# Constantly updated community best practice website?

Tags: vimrc

Is there an up-to-date community-driven<sup>1</sup> website which lists best practices regarding settings in `.vimrc`, plugins and/or tips to use vim? What is the best way to get to know up-to-date community-driven best practice regarding vim?

**The Problem**

I find that I spend too much time customizing my `.vimrc` after having read something about vim in the internet, only to later find out my customization was suboptimal. The same is sometimes true for learning habits how to use vim or for plugins.

Of course different people will judge different on what is suboptimal, but often enough I find myself agreeing to things *a community of active vim users recommends the most*. For example, posts/answers here or on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/) 
 with a lot of votes usually contain quality information.

However, StackExchange does not want open-ended question about best practices for vim. And on Reddit a post usually only discusses one or two topics. Just counting how often something appears in `.vimrc`s or how often a plugin is starred on Github also is no option, it leads to [suboptimal conclusions](http://vimawesome.com/?q=plugin%20manager).

I would like to use vim in a well-proven way with the input of a lot of users, and a good portion of that should ideally be a best practice site.

**Example what I look for**

A constantly available list like the following one, possibly sortable and with additional comments from other users:

<kbd>99 votes</kbd>[plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins)  If you use plugins, use [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as a plugin manager
<kbd>90 votes</kbd>[.vimrc](/questions/tagged/.vimrc)[plugin](/questions/tagged/plugin)  When building your `.vimrc`, start with an empty one. Only add what you
                                        understand. A good place to start are the settings in [vim-sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible).
<kbd>80 votes</kbd>[plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins)  [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) is a great syntax checker
<kbd>55 votes</kbd>[.vimrc](/questions/tagged/.vimrc)  Set your `<leader>` to space with `let mapleader = "\<space>"`
<kbd>40 votes</kbd>[general](/questions/tagged/general)  Remap Capslock to Control - to press `Esc` train yourself to use `<C-[>`
<kbd>30 votes</kbd>[plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins)  If you use plugins, use Vundle as a plugin manager
<kbd>14 votes</kbd>[general](/questions/tagged/general)  Instead of `di(` use `dib`, also for other verbs. For curly braces use `diB`
<kbd>12 votes</kbd>[general](/questions/tagged/general)  Remap Capslock to Esc
<kbd>10 votes</kbd>[.vimrc](/questions/tagged/.vimrc)  It is a great idea to use `Thisfunction()` in your `.vimrc` if you want...

---

<sub>**Footnotes**</sub>

<sub>1. With community driven I do not mean sites like [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) where users collaborate, but rather websites where people can cast up- and downvotes</sub>

Comment: Do you think a github repository could do the job ? From what you explained the website should allow collaborative work, tags, host, allow discussion through issues ... So it can be a simple way to achieve that :)

Comment: Something like http://vimrcfu.com/ maybe? It's mostly for snippets though.

Comment: @Nobe4: Looking at your Github page, you happen to be more familiar with Github than I am. I don't know whether a voting system would work there, which to me seems essential.

Comment: @tokoyami: Thanks for mentioning http://vimrcfu.com/. However its focus is somewhat different as you said and it seems to lack an active community.

Comment: @cbaumhardt : The voting system on github is quite a hot topic because many users wants one and no one is provided. But I am not quite sure how you would use a voting system.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but there is this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim/topics